# Why do I have to add the Permission into the Manifest although I do request them on start

Tags: android

On startup I ask for permission with a Codeblock like this:

```
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

The Request prompts but im not able to grant the permission until I add this to my Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Why do I have to add the `uses-permission` although it's only for system apps(at least android studio tells me that) and i request the needed permission on start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse Google needs to know what permissions your app uses for multiple purposes. One of them is to show the app permissions on your app's store listing.

Scanning all your codebase just to figure out what permissions your app is using is not really the best way to deal with it, is it?

Comment: Android itself also needs to know. Not all permissions are runtime, and the ones that are can be toggled from the app's info page in Settings. The latter wouldn't be possible if permissions weren't declared.